# Org-mode manual for header arguments is down

Tags: org-mode, manual

Does anyone know how to proceed? I'm searching for some information that was there. I don't know who to contact.

[image: The orgmode manual for header options is down]
https://orgmode.org/manual/Specific-header-arguments.html

Comment: There is no such section in the current version: just go to https://orgmode.org/manual and search from there. You can view the manual in your emacs with `C-h i g(org)`: maybe the version you have locally will still have the section.

Comment: Thank you, NickD. I didn't know they took it out on purpose. Ok, I will check the internal documentation

Comment: I don't think it was taken out: more likely, it was just renamed (and possibly reorganized a bit).